# Yii2: PHP mail without Swiftmailer?

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

It seems 1and1 web hosting service only allows plain PHP mail to send mail. But now Swiftmailer has thrown `Swift_MailTransport` away, so I'm unable to get simple PHP mail sending functionality using that class:

```
 'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
           'class'      => 'Swift_MailTransport', // NOT WORKING ANYMORE!!!
        ],
  ]
```

Is there any other class apart from `yii\swiftmailer\Mailer` I might use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

> The entire mail transport is deprecated. Use sendmail or smtp

https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/656/how-to-send-emails-using-smtp

```
 'mail' => [
     'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
     'transport' => [
         'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
         'host' => 'localhost',  // e.g. smtp.mandrillapp.com or smtp.gmail.com
         'username' => 'username',
         'password' => 'password',
         'port' => '587', // Port 25 is a very common port too
         'encryption' => 'tls', // It is often used, check your provider or mail server specs
     ],
 ],
```

Comment: It will not work, as I stated before: `1and1 web hosting service only allows plain PHP mail to send mail`

Comment: Plus my question assumes not using Swiftmailer in Yii2 (not even any other 3rd party mailer) but rather if there is any other built-in mailer class I could use.